# Hibernate: Avoid binding null to parameter in @Embeddable attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, embeddable

Hibernate scenario:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositeKey...{
  private String keyPart1;  
  private String keyPart2;
}

public class Entity{
  @Embedded
  private CompositeKey cKey;
  ...
}
```

Now when running this with a cKey with a value in only keyPart1 and keyPart2 == null I get a "binding null to parameter n" binding null to keyPart2.

Can I avoid that and have hibernate generate an SQL with only the parameters that actually has a value and omit the null ones?

So instead of

```
where keyPart1 = ? and keyPart2 = ?
```

I just want

```
where keyPart1 = ?
```

if cKey.keyPart2 == null

Thanks in advance...

./CJ

Comment: And what's the code triggering the query?

Comment: Kind of a sideways comment, but does it make sense in your domain to use an empty string instead of a null marker?

Comment: Solved it by dynamically constructing a where clause.

Comment: No - using an empty string wouldn't help